# Log to stdout and get string value of the stack trace

Tags: go

I have a logger that logs stack traces to `stdout`. I want to get the stack trace that was logged into a string value so I can send it as a debug email.

Here is my current code:

```
func (l *Logger) withStack(writer io.Writer, err error) error {
    err = errors.WithStack(err)
    fmt.Fprintf(writer, "%+v\n", err)
    return err
}

func (l *Logger) Error(err error) error {
    // Logs stack trace to `stdout`...
    l.withStack(os.Stdout, err)

    // Here I want to get the string value of what was logged to `stdout`.
}
```

But if the `stdout` stack trace looks like this:

```
foo
infrastructure/logger.(*Logger).withStack
    /Users/lansana/Projects/Go/src/app/src/infrastructure/logger/logger.go:40
infrastructure/logger.(*Logger).Error
    /Users/lansana/Projects/Go/src/app/src/infrastructure/logger/logger.go:50
main.main
    /Users/lansana/Projects/Go/src/app/src/microservices/api/main.go:44
runtime.main
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.9/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:185
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.9/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2337
```

...then the result of `err.Error()` in the email is just `foo`.

I guess that makes sense, because the error itself only contains `foo` and not the stack trace itself, but how can I get the exact stack trace as a string value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withStack` doesn't log to stdout: it logs to whatever implementation of `io.Writer` you provide it with. To easily get a string, consider passing it a `bytes.Buffer`.

Your `Error` func could look like this:

```
func sendErrorMail(s string) error {
    // Send the stack trace `s` by email
}

func (l *Logger) Error(err error) {
    // Get the stack trace as a string
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    l.withStack(buf, err)

    sendErrorMail(buf.String())
}
```

[Simple demonstration of this idea as a playground](https://play.golang.org/p/T8tkyLCu2Ko).

Comment: I could almost swear I tried passing in a buffer before instead of `os.Stdout`, but it only gave the error message and not the entire stack trace.... nonetheless, thanks this works.

Comment: Any idea how to make the string keep its formatting? I want all the `\n`'s to stay intact so the email can be formatted, it's just one big glob of a string in the email, but the stack trace is formatted.

Comment: @Lansana What's your email's content type? If it's `text/html`, you should use `<br>` instead of `\n`. If it's `text/plain`, `\n` should work.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. Mailer was sending `text/html` by default.